# How to redirect https app from www to non-www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I haven't found any answer to my question. I want that my React app would redirect requests from **www** to **non-www** and by default would open non-www URL correctly.

There are some of the answers how to redirect from **non-www** to **www**, but I need the opposite solution.

I'm running app with **https** turned in and now my *.htaccess* code looks like this and works well:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>


#######################################################################
# GENERAL                                                             #
#######################################################################

# Make apache follow sym links to files
Options +FollowSymLinks
# If somebody opens a folder, hide all files from the resulting folder list
IndexIgnore */*


#######################################################################
# REWRITING                                                           #
#######################################################################

# Enable rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# If its not HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

# Comment out the RewriteCond above, and uncomment the RewriteCond below if you're using a load balancer (e.g. CloudFlare) for SSL
# RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https

# Redirect to the same URL with https://, ignoring all further rules if this one is in effect
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

# If we get to here, it means we are on https://

# If the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# and the directory with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# and we are not opening the root already (otherwise we get a redirect loop)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\/$

# Rewrite all requests to the root



RewriteRule ^(.*) /

</ifModule>
```